# Dynamic values populated from Constants file into Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using a SDK which forces me to add the license key for it in Info.plist with a certain key name but i want to make sure i can dynamically populate those keys from a constant file which i can control and not checkin to my github repo.

Found few articles which talk about this : https://coderwall.com/p/euesdq/use-defined-values-in-info-plist

But doesn't get it to work, i am using Xcode 10 and Swift 4.

Thanks,

Comment: You have to define those constants value into build settings

Comment: Check this: https://gist.github.com/acrookston/55d69a16cd5363426dbf7a3d6a9ee6ce